DatePickerDialog. Change selected day background
I use a standard android picker. And now it looks like this:

Is there any way to change the background of the selected day so that it looks like this, for example?

Changing the color of the selected day does not cause problems. There is a variable in style for this. But it doesn't work that way with background.

As DatePickerDialog does not provide direct customization options for the selected day background. Try to create custom DatePickerDialog.
public class CustomDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {

    public CustomDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, listener, year, month, dayOfMonth);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DatePicker datePicker = getDatePicker();

        if (datePicker != null) {
            datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
            datePicker.getDayOfMonthTextView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_custom_selected_day_background);
        }
    }
}

And use in activity as below
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = (view, selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDayOfMonth) -> {
    // date selection
};

CustomDatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new CustomDatePickerDialog(getContext(), dateSetListener, year, month, dayOfMonth);
datePickerDialog.show();


sorry, but DatePicker's public methods do not contain getDayOfMonthTextView(). and setCalendarViewShown() is deprecated.
